# No map showing even though simple code

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to make a map adding a marker on the users location (accompanied by a searchbox) but even though my Javascript seems legit I can't figure out what seems to be the problem.

Background info:
I'm in the beginning of my learning, explaining all of the many and unnecessary divs with accompanying CSS. There seems to be no problem with the code, either the CSS or the Javascript, but still the map doesn't show up on the screen. The map has worked, unfortunatly the code is gone, when there was a standard center (set with cordinates).

If more info is requiered and/or presented in a different way, please let me know. There is a working snippet for testing. Just click "Run code snippet".

```js
function initialize(position) {
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  var setting = {
    center: location,
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), setting);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    title: 'Marker'
  });


}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.mapContent {
  padding: 0;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
.mapContainer {
  width: 830px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div #googleMap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 250px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
div #searchbox {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#floating-panel {
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: darkred;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mapContent">
  <div class="mapContainer">
    <div id="searchbox">
      <div id="floating-panel">
        <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Sök">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="googleMap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/wexd3spp/6/ everything seems ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following error on your page:

> “Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined”

Remember that the API can not be loaded after the document has finished loading you'll need to do that asynchronously.

Also, you may have forgotten to add the api URL reference: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

Check out this fiddle, everything works perfectly:

https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/wexd3spp/6/

Code to enable the navigation:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: inside the  head tag like this <head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in the browser. Can you show in my code where to put it because I really can't understand why it is not working.